# How to communicate with a polymorphic child component in Elm?

Tags: functional-programming, polymorphism, elm, unification, union-types

My main program has an `update` function of

```
update : Msg -> Model -> ( Model, Cmd Msg )
```

To communicate with sub-components we can add another variant and wrap our messages in a new message

```
type alias Model =
    { ...
    , child : Child.Model
    }

type Msg
    = ...
    | ChildMsg Child.Msg

update msg model =
    case msg of
        ...

        ChildMsg childMsg ->
          let
              ( childModel, cmd ) =
                  Child.update childMsg model.child

              updatedModel =
                  { model | child = childModel }

              childCmd =
                Cmd.map ChildMsg cmd
          in
               ( updatedModel, childCmd )
```

However this seem challenging if the type of my sub-component's `update` function does not match the parent. Consider a child with a polymorphic update function:

```
-- PolymorphicChild.elm

update : Msg a -> Model -> ( Model, Cmd (Msg a) )
```

When running a command from this module, I must wrap it

```
PolymorphicChild.someCommand : Cmd (Msg Foo)

PolymorphicChild.someCommand
  |> Cmd.map PolymorphicChild
```

However, this produces a `Msg (PolymorphicChild.Msg Foo)`, not the `Msg PolymorphicChild.Msg` my App is expecting.

```
The right side of (|>) is causing a type mismatch.

(|>) is expecting the right side to be a:

    Cmd (PolyMorphicChild.Msg Foo) -> a

But the right side is:

    Cmd Polymorphic.Msg -> Cmd Msg
```

I tried adding a polymorphic parameter to `App.Msg`

```
-- App.elm

type Msg a =
   = ..
   | PolymorphicChildMsg (PolymorphicChild.Msg a)
```

But it basically blows up my entire program. Every function involving `App.Msg` needs to somehow be changed to work with the new child component.

How can I unify the two types and get the two components working together?

Comment: Can you give some more insight into what you're trying to accomplish? What is the child's purpose? There may be a different approach than bubbling an undetermined type argument up the object graph.

Comment: Making an Elm front end for Wordpress – there's been some interesting challenges along the way... Here's a [link](https://ellie-app.com/Hrqjj3knZza1) to show you what I'm talking about. I can't post all of it on Ellie because it only allows one file, but I think it's enough to get the picture. I've considered just bringing all of this into the main `App` but I was hoping to keep Wordpress backend-related stuff in an isolated module. I'm new to type-based programming so I'm probably doing something dumb...

Comment: This is one of those things where a lot has been made in recent months of trying to get newbies to stop thinking in "components", which Elm doesn't really have. Check out "The life of a File" https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=XpDsk374LDE or "Scaling Elm Apps" https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=DoA4Txr4GUs for a better theoretical grounding. I still make apps all the time where I have something similar to "sub-components", but I try to go with a flat structure for as long as possible, and then refactor when it gets too big and there are too many un-related features in the same update function.

Comment: @wmakley Thanks for sharing. I actually watched those two videos last week and refactored this module entirely based on what I learned. No more child component :D

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think the problem is that you're leaking too much information in your publicly exposed `Msg` type. Your use of the type parameter of `Msg a` seems limited to a known set of types, either an `Author`, `Category`, `Post`, or `Tag`. From skimming your code, it looks like it will never be anything but one of those four, so the fact that you are abstracting things in this manner should be kept inside of this module rather than exposing it and burdening any other code that may be pulling this in.

I think you need to move the abstraction down a level to avoid parameterizing your public `Msg` type. I would suggest having four concrete constructors for `Msg` instead of parameterizing it, and shift the abstraction down to a helper `LoadInfo a` type:

```elm
type alias LoadInfo a =
    { worker : Worker a
    , url : Url
    , result : Result Http.Error ( Int, List a )
    }

type Msg
    = LoadPost (LoadInfo Post)
    | LoadCategory (LoadInfo Category)
    | LoadTag (LoadInfo Tag)
    | LoadAuthor (LoadInfo Author)
```

Comment: This looks much nicer, but how do I construct these messages from an Http command?

Comment: Something like `decoder |> Http.get url |> Http.toTask |> Task.attempt (LoadInfo worker url)` ?

Comment: Just shooting from the hip here, but I think this should work: `Http.send (Load << LoadInfo worker url)`

Comment: The power of this is sort of blowing my mind. I'm going to see how other areas of my program can be improved with this technique. Thanks, Chad.

Comment: Or even `Http.send (LoadInfo worker url) |> Cmd.map LoadPost` for those that understand it from a `Cmd.map` perspective. Functional programming is premium.